# Broadcast multiple hostnames on LAN

Tags: debian, networking, hostname

I have a home server set up to which I have assigned multiple IPs. The network is 192.168.196.0/24, and all the IPs from 130 to 139 are assigned to the same device (the home server). In that server, I have set up a DNS that assigns a url/domain/hostname (don't really know the exact word for this) to each IP. It looks like this:

```
dashboard     IN    A     192.168.196.130
ssh           IN    A     192.168.196.131
ftp           IN    A     192.168.196.132
```

This means that if I have the DNS setup in a machine, I can do `nslookup ssh.server.kolt` and it will show me the IP `192.168.196.131`.

Now, I did all of this just because why not, and because I didn't like having all the services on the same domain (koltserver.local) and give each one of them a different port.

Now that I have set up multiple IPs for the server, is there a way I can access each of them separately using the .local domain? the hostname of the server is `koltserver`, and currently, pinging that domain shows me the 130 IP always. Is it possible to set up different hostnames for each one?

To sum it up, I gave my server 10 IP addresses, and now I want to see if I can give a different .local domain to each of them so that I can use them without having to set up custom DNS like I have already done.

Comment: `avahi-publish-address` seems to be what you want

Answer (score 0):

For mDNS-based `.local`, if you are using Avahi as the responder, use `/etc/avahi/hosts` to define names that you want Avahi to publish. (Systemd-resolved does not have an equivalent feature.)

Comment: When I di hat, `avahi` only publishes one of the hosts. The issue is described by another user [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729087/avahi-local-name-collision)